# Renaming a variable in GNU Octave

Tags: variables, octave, rename

Let's say I have a variable `g` in my GNU Octave workspace. How can I rename it to `f`?

I tried using the `rename` function but I believe it is for another purpose.

Comment: MATLAB is not Octave and code that works in one doesn't necessarily work in the other. Please don't spam irrelevant tags and pick the one for the language you're actually using. As most people who use Octave know to explicitly specify it I left that language, if you actually use MATLAB, please change the languages, but don't add both.

Comment: @Adriaan actually this piece of code works in MATLAB and Octave.

Comment: But as the tags clearly state: not everything works in both. If I want to give you a solution in MATLAB, there's no guarantee it works in Octave. Hence, please keep the tags separate, unless, as the tag excerpt states, you are explicitly asking about the differences between the two languages. Having both tags forces you to write code which works in both languages, which is a pain for e.g. loops or functions due to `end` not being general in Octave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, `rename` is for files on the filesystem. To "rename" a variable, just assign it to a new variable and clear the old one.

```matlab
f = g;
clear g
```